# Posting data to a form using HttpWebRequest won't work

Tags: c#, post, httpwebrequest

I have create a [form](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AipeKMUl_c57dDYyM0MxQUYzZnAwTGFfeFA0VG9VVUE) here and try to post data in it using httpwebrequest. data is not submitted into this [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AipeKMUl_c57dDYyM0MxQUYzZnAwTGFfeFA0VG9VVUE#gid=0) and i don't know why

```
    private const string PostURI = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/formResponse?formkey=dDYyM0MxQUYzZnAwTGFfeFA0VG9VVUE6MQ&amp;ifq";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        BeginGetRequestExample();            
        Console.Read();
    }

    private static void BeginGetRequestExample()
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(PostURI);
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestCallback), request);
    }

    private static void GetRequestCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;

        using (var postStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult))
        {
            string postData = "entry.0.single=testdata";
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, postData.Length);
        }

    }
```

Comment: please define 'didn't work'...

Comment: u have 666 repo, that's creepy D::D:D lol

Answer (score 0):

No where in your code you are checking to see the status of the Asynchronous job.You can use the ResetEvents to make sure that you wait for the asynchronous work to complete

Declare a `ManualResetEvent`

```
private static ManualResetEvent workCompleted= new ManualResetEvent(false);
```

Add **workCompleted.WaitOne()** to your BeginGetRequestExample.Now this method will wait for the Asynchronous method to complete.

```
 request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestCallback), request);
 workCompleted.WaitOne();//This will block the thread.
```

Add **workCompleted.Set()** to your `GetRequestCallback`.The set() call will signal the completion of execution to BeginGetRequestStream

```
 using (var postStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult))
            {
                string postData = "entry.0.single=testdata";
                byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
                postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, postData.Length);
            }

 workCompleted.Set();//work completed,signal BeginGetRequestExample.
```

Comment: have made an edit,please check.you need to use manual reset event.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience... I think the data you posted probably not right.

This is the raw HttpPost

```
POST https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/formResponse?formkey=dDYyM0MxQUYzZnAwTGFfeFA0VG9VVUE6MQ&ifq HTTP/1.1
Host: docs.google.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 62
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Origin: https://docs.google.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
X-Chrome-Variations: CPO1yQEIl7bJAQietskBCKS2yQEIp7bJAQiptskBCLW2yQEIsIPKAQ==
Referer: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/viewform?formkey=dDYyM0MxQUYzZnAwTGFfeFA0VG9VVUE6MQ&amp;ifq
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.6
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: PREF=ID=95ae5350cc16c940:U=28fe773a18c2dbe6:LD=en:TM=1345120351:LM=1345194034:GM=1:S=3Cn9QquJ5Czg34G0; __utma=184632636.1591015415.1346839842.1346839842.1346839842.1; __utmz=184632636.1346839842.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); NID=62=1rseSYPhjiIKnlAgPIthlh-KblNw8OVSOJuFL54wW2wX9HmucRXT83vYgz-JAUlgGuFv8BJTQutADeZvxtQnOnnUtOhckpRN6Q39zeRb9yKqCp2p1U-ZB3mhmkPwz4Iz0j3FHeGty9yDqOjlma5rG5GtgRyl6z7YakbICD7ckt11JJm3-jrFemtNg-wH1sqWZWiThPzb4R40Q3RAeohBgvU3-nJ38_VZDG9rA7pTVvQ7jw; HSID=AqYa-X7Si3Broi94c; SSID=AxGpbOiAWCleF5e9z; APISID=8Fgs9inkdycfWieu/AEg1bwhd3Aesfa3XR; SAPISID=G9xcUdWksRD2dzMM/AbmBuqsL_bNcslBTQ; WRITELY_SID=DQAAAGEBAACUg03i_4fbFZEg_gr-iMZ6zg_h5P-tqox77Gw_mLIqgQtDD0OyUGTw0Dn1p5plW1rQnqNuDYrG8XscJCeAyWiL-8p5sM0qtZGUNKX24BgZarvYBWS78x6kEKsoGKibwVKr2r481JBN7Q-nr7gjLw6A6aKD0mezPGP7PHRc7xZ7g1vId50WOyb2_0hqOzJ6nXSu_3y1yce4ursF3aqBfHzbCHnPVN6WNhCjZbkqCGiFNDIcVz-POlyB5QTXxtAYNGUgJdAXpXQPS3ET7MAOLCH4roafbFDi18lQ7qvuvEz1A8QvGNhCi2jnEr_STmkRWfmnVP_0rahkaDpPkFmg2TJd6e8s6xdzu9UL6bxHshacaapu7CEj-pJIL8zq2PVEkJLs7DcvvMIdCDxDOtt9j5Jgmq0uDjto94EvnBnBTcnwWpZZY0-bT9yl6m9Nt3pMgtl4VBYJgwEWjPV46OfYdgJosJKEHXo0wgDs9YomzxHvsQ; S=explorer=gpeJDnKwHily6YMp3ZAyaQ; SS=DQAAAGIBAACUg03i_4fbFZEg_gr-iMZ6cA1_10PYYPfBefa6O8m4JId5S6dOVXANhELN3jPzvZxjjqlGEbGrvah6eNypAvojSKB4X_xdioJLbY3T80h9oBV1doK6KY7-hwrlKj62pjLxQ-ZoHu-pfZc-8WdkowaEPOkg4wS_ZblJfMAykXbufmDMg4u1IPt95A4vI45BBBL71XcT8S4PgI4UfXFkNkX7DqxfOYFUiCnVHyLMaSRE_N9mfdfyLuYAwm_e84G2COiOeEW-0D5dytWlAPznvIgKVbxcdeBosZJsFOc_pgeVVUCCAyQIMLdqaWCv_FE-aO5dV73a2vLOmgETg34VM1fV7fxR0b_hF88njjJpeuQVBu1MgFWWyARsO56ZrJ89QrC7PwyCLNm-lsjf0WXDZz6BbP4zw-U2I_DBxJsQ4XsqXc2663BUK5k9Sg7Yy8ULhjZkxILYzQd016m0yE9cJlHBEx4MMmm6fBDlkzzXs8OIHA; SID=DQAAAF8BAABm0OXzbbbSZWD3Qj4rTcK4dDifbWX0DEgZ3cBs_xxFxCJJj35PBe6ORIspSn-inbK3g4fU6e6OsedvVP11l_Rf9GOA-BucVEYOpL8f7LWSbybhRD9Db9vQWmoCRiterbKY67_4nJYRaaY69djDdpJUXpykAYq5XGCWoX89qQUbkZmixKUZU2dXIPgxdpnEwmSJNcspjuLfJWhRMRnIc4cGhV1osB2W33XriFWZQ-vIfUoIAygrM-a_zpK4-Bw0L4hym8aVdMv2pB9QwEzPFKzNBa7l3PLjs7dHWqu-btHnVNf_j9tZk0GqE3EjrsdSeJpTaRfwW0vBhdemHbPJtIq5DmdAAwNDV3_RM79iS6S1vyszAb_G51ZDWH1-1IR8FjbgTPJT2llGmwYKe9C63LK5_WzqenwoPQnJj5kwUEeBnqqs_9nKOD2cFxDhuVky_Z5AIuhVZAx2sUzgIG8uB1PQ

entry.0.single=abcdefg&pageNumber=0&backupCache=&submit=Submit
```

This is the raw http response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://docs.google.com
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
X-Robots-Tag: noindex, nofollow, nosnippet
Date: Mon, 29 Oct 2012 09:47:43 GMT
Expires: Mon, 29 Oct 2012 09:47:43 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Server: GSE
Content-Length: 1225

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"><html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Thanks!</title>

<link href='/static/spreadsheets/client/css/627030122-form_response_compiled.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet'>
<style type="text/css">
      .ss-logo {background:transparent url("https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/spreadsheets/forms/sprites_2.png") no-repeat}
    </style></head>
<body><div class="ss-container"><div class="ss-resp-card"><div class="ss-confirmation">TestPost</div>
<div class="ss-custom-resp">เราได้บันทึกคำตอบของคุณไว้แล้ว </div>
<div class="ss-opt-actions">

</div>
<hr class="ss-break">
<div class="ss-footer"><div class="ss-footer-txt"><a class="ss-actions-link" href="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/viewform?formkey=dDYyM0MxQUYzZnAwTGFfeFA0VG9VVUE6MQ&amp;ifq">Submit another response</a>
|
<a class="ss-actions-link" href="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/newform?ref=submitpage">Create your own form</a></div>
<a class="ss-logo-link" href="https://docs.google.com/"><div class="ss-logo">&nbsp;&nbsp;</div></a></div></div></div></body></html>
```

What you need to do probably is to construct the exact HttpPost.